# JavaScript variable not updating in loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do the following:

a) Add a class from an array containing the values one, two, three to all the divs with the  class `.tab-col`. The first div in the class `.tab-col` should have the class `one`, second div should have class `two`, etc. => This is what `addCol()` does in code below

b) After a) is done, trying to grab the `tab-col` divs, and adding the class one to the first child element (`col-attr`), two to the second, etc. . => What `addAttr()` is attempting to do.

I have succeeded with a) and partially succeeded with b). The problem I am having is that only the `.tab-col one`'s children elements are being labelled with the classes `one`, `two`, `three`. Whereas the other `tab-col`s children are not adding the classes one, two and three to their children elements.

```js
function addCol() {
   var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-col");
   var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"];
   var index = 0,
     length = elements.length;
   for (; index < length; index++) {
     elements[index].classList.add(array[index]);
   }
 }

 addCol();

 function addAttr() {
   var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-col");
   var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"];

   var index = 0,
     length = elements.length;
   for (; index < length; index++) {
     var select = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-col" + "." + array[index] + "> .col-attr");
     for (var i = 0, length = select.length; index < length; i++) {
       select[i].classList.add(array[i]);
     }
   }
 }

 addAttr();
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tab-col">
    <div class="col-attr"></div>
    <div class="col-attr"></div>
    <div class="col-attr"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-col">
    <div class="col-attr"></div>
    <div class="col-attr"></div>
    <div class="col-attr"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-col">
    <div class="col-attr"></div>
    <div class="col-attr"></div>
    <div class="col-attr"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSBIN replicating the problem: http://jsbin.com/hohuxewixi/edit?html,css,js,output

(Note: Because there is no content, you will have to open up your browser's console in the output area (inspect element))

My question how can I have `.tab-col two` and `.tab-col three` to have their children elements (`.col-attr`) have the classes one, two and three, just as it is for `.tab-col one` (if you look at the completed JSBIN that will run the JavaScript)?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is `classList`?

Comment: Looks like you are re-using `length` in the inner `for` loop.

Comment: @Michael [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: @Ibu I'd like to have the div with the class tab-col two, and tab-col three to have its children elements (col attr) have the classes one, two and three (class one to first child, class two to second, etc.)

Comment: Lets begin with this. `for(var i=0, length = select.length; index < length; i++){`. `length` is already defined, `index`is not your counter.

Comment: Pretty straight forward -> https://jsfiddle.net/che2a8km/

Comment: @JimCote Could you perhaps clarify on this, I'm not 100% seeing what you are seeing?

Comment: Or -> https://jsfiddle.net/che2a8km/1/

Comment: Thanks @adeneo for your efforts. I am not familiar with ES6 and those functions. Could you help using the methods I have used above to figure out the solution? BTW, I'd like the second tab-col and third tab-col to have the classes one, two and three applied to the elements (as in your second example).

Comment: Should be trivial to use regular loops instead -> https://jsfiddle.net/che2a8km/2/

Comment: @the12 `length = elements.length` and `length = select.length`. It's the same length. Variables have function scope, not loop scope.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @adeneo. Your code is far more efficient than mine (the corrected one), I'm going to spend the night looking at it and trying to understand it. In the future, I may ask a question regarding your example on this question, if I don't fully understand it.

Comment: Can I ask why you are adding numbered classes to your html? For css styling? Or is it for Selecting the elements with JavaScript or something else?

Comment: @John Absolutely. I plan on a special kind of table from these classes. Each `.tab-col` is a separate column that will have borders and margins around them. This first `.tab-col` will be the a column with the attributes in them (name, picture, etc.), and the ones after will be different columns . For this to work, each one of the `col-attr` (cells within the column) width needs to be controlled using classes. For example, all divs with the class `col-attr one` will need to be the same size. I could have done it with CSS, but with apps, it may be inefficient to write col-attr hundred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are ovveriding the values of `index` and `length` inside the inner loop. Use different variables like this:

```
function addAttr(){
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-col");
    var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"];

    // the index and length that you're overriding inside the loop
    var index = 0, length = elements.length;
    for( ;index < length; index++){
        var select = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-col" + "." + array[index] + "> .col-attr");

        // you shouldn't override the values of index and length, use other variables
        var index2 = 0, length2 = select.length;
        for(; index2 < length2; index2++){
            select[index2].classList.add(array[index2]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```js
function addCol() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-col");
  var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"];
  var index = 0,
    length = elements.length;
  for (; index < length; index++) {
    elements[index].classList.add(array[index]);
  }
}

addCol();




function addAttr() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-col");
  var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"];

  // the index and length that you're overriding inside the loop
  var index = 0,
    length = elements.length;
  for (; index < length; index++) {
    var select = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-col" + "." + array[index] + "> .col-attr");

    // you shouldn't override the values of index and length, use other variables
    var index2 = 0,
      length2 = select.length;
    for (; index2 < length2; index2++) {
      select[index2].classList.add(array[index2]);
    }
  }
}

addAttr();
```

```html
<div class="tab-col">
  <div class="col-attr">A</div>
  <div class="col-attr">B</div>
  <div class="col-attr">C</div>
</div>

<div class="tab-col">
  <div class="col-attr">D</div>
  <div class="col-attr">E</div>
  <div class="col-attr">F</div>
</div>

<div class="tab-col">
  <div class="col-attr"></div>
  <div class="col-attr"></div>
  <div class="col-attr"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have tried copying and pasting that answer inside my addAttr function in both JSBin and in Atom. This code unfortunately does not work. Only the first child in the first `.tab-col` has the class one in it.

Comment: @the12 I had a little mistake `i++` should be `index2++`. I updated my answer. It's working as you can see in the snippet. By the way, if you want the `.col-attr`s of a `.tab-col` to not have the same class, then change `index` to `index2` where I commented `// \/ this index should ...`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and the knowledge that I have overridden values if you name them the same thing. However, unfortunately the code is not working as the children divs (`.col-attr`) is now for the first `tab-col` (one, one, one), and the second (two, two, two). I'd like the children divs for each of `tab-col` classes to have the classes one, two and three.

Comment: @the12 I updated my answer anyway! I thought you wanted it like that. Anyway, the new updated answer works as you want!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to reconsider your approach.

CSS has a powerful construct for selecting particular child elements called `nth-of-type`. [Here's an MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) about it. This nth-of-type differs from another `nth-child` selector only in the slightest way and it may be what your after in this and other circumstances. [Here's an mdn reference on nth-child.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```js
// querySelector and querySelectorAll in JS support css selectors
// so there is no problem using the nth child selector
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".col-attr:nth-child(3)");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
  elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  elements[i].style.width = "100px";
  elements[i].style.height = "20px";
}
```

```css
/* We can select the first child columns of each row like so */
.col-attr:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

/* We can select the second child of each row like this */
.col-attr:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class = "table">
  <div class="tab-col">
    <div class="col-attr"></div>
    <div class="col-attr"></div>
    <div class="col-attr"></div>
  </div>

<div class = "tab-col">
  <div class="col-attr"></div>
  <div class="col-attr"></div>
  <div class="col-attr"></div>
</div>

<div class = "tab-col">
  <div class="col-attr"></div>
  <div class="col-attr"></div>
  <div class="col-attr"></div>
</div>
```

You can do more advanced selections with nth child. Inside the parentheses when you add a single number like `:nth-child(1)` it says select that numbered nth child and that one only. When you type `:nth-child(2n)` it understands it as selecting every number that is even. When you type `:nth-child(2n+1)` it understands it as select every odd number. For any of these nth child selections to understand it you need to know that `n` takes on the values of the nonnegative integers (`{0,1,2,3, ...}`). When you type `:nth-child(3n+5)` the first thing you can think of it selecting is `3(0)+5`th element or the 5th element then it will select the `3(1)+5`th element or the 8th element and so on incrementing n each time by one until it selects all elements that are available and in the context that its selecting from. If you think of it as `an+b` with a and b as variables a nice way to think of this is starting from the number `b` select that element and every `a`th element after it.

Comment: lol funny thing is I actually knew about these selectors, but did not use them. Yeah, this is way easier than doing what I was doing. Definitely going to be playing around with this today. Thank you for this very helpful piece of advice!

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
for(var i=0, length = select.length; index < length; i++){
```

You should use i instead of index. Just a copy and paste error by the looks of it.

```
for(var i=0, length = select.length; i < length; i++){
```

Comment: Changed i to index. It did not do anything to the code in question.

Comment: You need to rename `length` as well.